# StdIn.readString() from algs4 Princeton Algorithm Course in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Having trouble using StdIn.readString() from algs4 Princeton Algorithm Course in Eclipse.

```
    String item2 = "test1";
    item2 = StdIn.readString();
    System.out.println("test2");
```

The program would not execute any codes after StdIn.readString(); 
How would the method StdIn.readString() take the string input?
Stack overflow says "Run Configuration" -> "Arguments". But it doesn't seem to work for me.

Resolved: As cricket_007 says, it was waiting for my input in the Eclipse console.

Comment: We don't know what `StdIn` is, it is a custom class for your course.  However, as a guess, you probably have to type something into the console window.

Comment: These 3 lines of code will not run without a `public class` and a `public static void main()` method

Comment: @JimGarrison http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdIn.java.html

Comment: That's off-topic then.  Any answer would apply only to that specific course.

Comment: @JimGarrison How do you mean? The same question could be asked with `new Scanner().next()`, which is essentially all that method does

Comment: https://github.com/kevin-wayne/algs4/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/StdIn.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The program would not execute any codes after StdIn.readString();

It is waiting for user input. You have to actually type something and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the Eclipse console.

Try running this, for example

```
System.out.print("Type Here >>> ");
item2 = StdIn.readString();
System.out.println("You entered: " + item2);
```

Comment: How do you know for sure that the OP has not done that

Comment: Because OP would have seen `"test2"`printed and not claimed "nothing runs" after this line.

Comment: Well, there could be something wrong in OP's version of `StdIn.readString()` too. However I know you are right :)

Comment: Thank you! Works now! Never use the console for input.

Comment: Got it. Another Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Answering this in 2020 just in case anybody is still wondering. As cricket_007 said, StdIn.readString() waits for console input. To add to his answer, StdIn.readString() will only read the first token. In order for all tokens to be read, StdIn.readString() should be ran in a loop.

```
 while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
      string value = StdIn.readString();
      StdOut.println(value);
  }
```

The above is referenced here https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html

Comment: what should I pass in input console, as we are checking Std input is empty or not in the loop, my doubt is when does it will come out of the loop. Like for how long should I keep entering input values to the console. What to do if I want to pass input.txt file? I am using `In in = new In(args[0])` insead of StdIn.

Comment: First off StdIn.readString() isn't for reading from files. The course is misleading. StdIn.readString() is for reading the tokens you input. I considers anything a token that as space, regardless of how many spaces are between. The first argument is just the maximum number of tokens you what to print out. When the program is launched, it waits for your input. You enter the tokens in the console. Then you hit enter for a newline. Hit ctrl-D to exit the loop. You can read more about ctrl-D here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401347/how-to-make-stdin-isempty-return-true/52006268#52006268